# undefined scope into $watch

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a directive named **dir** with:

```
ng-model="job.start_date"

comparison-date="job.end_date
```

Into `scope.$watch("comparisonDate...` I want to access my ng-model value. The problem is that scope is undefined into watch's callback function. **The Question is: How can I get the ng-value inside this function?**

```
.directive("dir", function() {
    return {
        scope: {
            comparisonDate: "=",
            ngModel: "="
        },

        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
            var foo = scope.ngModel;
            scope.$watch("comparisonDate", function(value, oldValue) {
                console.log(value); //comparisonDate showing value properly
                console.log(scope.ngModel); //Undefined
                    console.log(foo) //shows value but it's not refreshing. It shows allways the initial value
            })
        }
    };
})
```

the view...

```
<input dir type="text" ng-model="job.start_date" comparison-date="job.end_date"/>
```

Comment: Do console.log(scope); ngModel may be contained in scope.$parent or even scope.$parent.$parent depending on your app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During the linking phase of the directive, the value may not be available. You can use `$observe` to observe the value change.

```
attrs.$observe("comparisonDate", function(a) {
    console.log(scope.ngModel);
})
```

Comment: I'm afraid this is not correct. `$observe` only works with attributes that contain interpolation, thus only `@` properties can be "observed"; to monitor a property with two-way binding, `$watch` is the right way to go.

Comment: @MichaelBenford No. The purpose of `$observe` is to delay the evaluation. And there is no reason it only deals with interpolation but not the normal attributes.

Comment: indeed, but it only works with attributes that contain interpolation. You can't use it to monitor a property bound with `=`.

Comment: @MichaelBenford Why? Create a fiddle to show me an example please.

Comment: That's by design. Take a look [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive): "Use $observe to observe the value changes of attributes that contain interpolation (e.g. src="{{bar}}")". It simply won't work with `=` properties. See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rkK8v/)

Comment: @MichaelBenford Obviously it renders the correct value. I think the doc is quite clear, when the model contains the interpolation, you need to use $observe, when it doesn't contain the interpolation, why you can't use it? Read it again. And OP wants to access the value and he doesn't say anything about watching it later.

Comment: Sorry, the correct value? Perhaps we should move this conversation to a chat, if you want to.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38206/discussion-between-michael-benford-and-sza)

Answer (score 1):

`ng-model` is built-in directive that tells Angular to do two-way data binding. http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngModel

It looks like you are using the value of properties of the same object `job` to do comparison. If you want to stick with `ng-model`, you can use `NgModelController`: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngModel.NgModelController

Then change the view to:

```
<input dir type="text" ng-model="job"/>
```

and change the directive to:

```
.directive("dir", function() {
    return {
        require: '?ngModel', // get a hold of NgModelController
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
            // access the job object
            ngModel.$formatters.push(function(job){
                console.log(job.start_date);
                console.log(job.end_date);
            });
        }
    };
})
```

Or you can change the attribute name from `ng-model` to some words haven't reserved. For example change the view like:

```
<input dir type="text" comparison-start-date="job.start_date" comparison-end-date="job.end_date"/>
```

Comment: You can use `NgModelController.$modelValue` to get the value bound to the input control and keep the OP's original markup.

Comment: @MichaelBenford Yes, you are right. In that way, the OP's original markup doesn't need to be changed. But it looks kinda wired if you can use `NgModelController` to access the object and then you need another attribute to get the different property value of the same object.

Comment: I agree with you it's strange, but if the OP is implementing a generic directive, I guess the property bound to `ng-model` could be a totally different one bound to `comparison-date`. If it's such a case, I think the original markup makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

Try `scope.$watch(attrs.comparisonDate, ...)` and then use `attrs.ngModel`